# Flutter bottomnavigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do I achieve that red bottomnavigation button?

I am using a floating action button on the app but I only want to use the styling of the bottomnavigation for onSelected or something like that.

[image: The app in question]

Comment: BottomNavigationBarItem has `backgroundColor`, is not work?

Comment: What exactly you want? BottomNavigation or just styling of BottomNavigation?

Comment: Styling of a BottomNavigation especially the clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own bottom nav bar. For example with an column where you place the Nav bar as Container with an fixed height (for Android around 56.0 px) to the bottom and inside the container place the row Widget where each children is one of your nav bar items.

So If you want to highlight the selected nav bar item just use an container as wrapper of your nav bar item and give this one the color like that:

```
color: activeNavItemId == <idOfYourNavItem> 
     ? Color.red
     : Color.black;
```

Note: So every time you click on one of this nav bar items you have to set the activeNavItemId with the id of this button and then call setState.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and update you. Also, is there away to extend the BottomNavigation and then override some behaviour?